# Excel formula to output line breaks to word document

Tags: excel, ms-word, excel-formula

I have an Excel spreadsheet that is linked to a Word document.
This word document is a letter.

I have a field in Excel that is optional for the user to enter data into, but if something is present then it needs to be included into the letter.

I can do all that just fine, but this additional data needs to be in its own paragraph on the Word document. Hence some new lines need to be introduced to separate this new paragraph from the rest of the text, but also for these lines not to be present if the data isn't present.

On my Excel worksheet I have discovered this is how to do this:

```
=IF(B36="","",CHAR(10)&B36&CHAR(10))
```

However, on the word doc, this outputs as:

[image]

I do not want the " characters, but need the line breaks that it gives.

Entering the line breaks on the word doc beforehand is not an option, as I say, they need to NOT be present if this data is not present.

The output to Word is perfect if no data is present in the field. No line breaks and no " characters.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but if its quick to check you might try instead of using CHAR(10), use Alt+Enter to add line breaks to the formula its self : `IF(B36="","","'Alt+Enter'"&B36&"'Alt+Enter'"). The Alt+Enter refers to the keys on your keyboard rather than typing out the words, it should spread the formula over multiple lines

Comment: Just tried but It doesn't give the line breaks unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

char(10) is the number for new line in Excel, char(11) is the number for new line in Word.

Was simply a case of replacing 10 with 11

```
=IF(B36="","",CHAR(11)&B36&CHAR(11))
```

Which gives the desired effect:

[image]